# WCF REST Service hosted in Console Application minimum example

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I've just started working with WCF and tried creating a small REST HTTP service.
If it is hosted in the IIS, it works fine. However now I am trying to host it
in a console application. I've worked through several tutorials but can't get it to work.

My guess is that it is a fairly simple mistake in the Program.cs since the same service works if it is hosted within IIS.

If I try accessing http://localhost:8080/Products/ I get a webpage that says no endpoint found.

Program.cs

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");

// Create the ServiceHost.
using (WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(ProductRESTService), baseAddress))
{
     host.Open();

     Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
     Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");                 
     Console.ReadLine();

     // Close the ServiceHost.
     host.Close();
}
```

IProductRestService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProductRESTService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "http://localhost:8080/Products/")]
    List<Product> getProductList();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "http://localhost:8080/Product/{id}/")]
    Product getProduct(string id);
}
```

ProductRestService.cs

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class ProductRESTService : IProductRESTService
{
    public Product getProduct(string id)
    {
        return Products.Instance.GetProduct(Convert.ToInt32(id));
    }

    public List<Product> getProductList()
    {
        return Products.Instance.ProductList;
    }
}
```

The Product and Products classes are here http://pastebin.com/FRFxsWBU but I doubt that they are relevant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution myself. The mistake was really rather stupid: In the IProductRestService.cs the UriTemplates are supposed to be **templates** not URIs themselves.

Now I have this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/Products/")]
    List <Product> getProductList();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/Product/{id}/")]
    Product getProduct(string id);
```

And it works as expected.

Comment: Addionally you can also checkout my WCF REST sample for hosting in console here at [github](https://github.com/vendettamit/WebHttpBehaviorExtensions). This project have extensions for WCF REST services which are not available out of the box. Also checkout a [complete series](http://www.cshandler.com/2015/10/securing-wcf-rest-api-using-ssl-and.html) on Hosting/Managing/Securing Rest if intereseted.

Comment: @vendettamit I was able to use your example on gitHub to build a minimal working example with self-hosting in a console app (after massive simplification!). Was a great help!